# Adjust screen brightness hotkeys not working in Vaio laptop

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio

I formatted my Vaio VPCEA37FL laptop and later I installed a clean version of Windows 7.

The problem is, adjust screen brightness hotkeys do not work anymore. I have installed every driver from Sony support website that I think it could be related, but no luck. I contacted Sony support, but they told me it is necessary to modify the registry and they want to charge me 80 dollars (it includes a computer scan).

So, does anybody know what do I need to do to fix it? Do I really need to modify the registry?

Thanks.

Comment: If you know where the registry is located, then that would be a good course of action.  Then again, you could always backup all of your data and restore the factory settings... which I would imagine is probably not feasible.

Comment: Also I would keep an eye on [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/472081/can-i-force-a-greater-screen-brightness-from-windows-command-prompt#comment556609_472081).