# Set monitor 1 brightness according monitor 2 brightness

Tags: multiple-monitors, powershell

Is possible to set monitor 1 (EIZO, which has ambient sensors) brightness according monitor 2 (BenQ XL2411) brightness?

I found that is possible to set through powercfg. [Can I force a greater screen brightness from Windows Command Prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/472081/can-i-force-a-greater-screen-brightness-from-windows-command-prompt)

Both monitors can have different pool of brightness, this can be solved by simple condition in powershell.
Another question is, how to periodicaly control brightness of monitor 1 ?

Thanks

Comment: [Use PowerShell to Report and Set Monitor Brightness](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/25/use-powershell-to-report-and-set-monitor-brightness/)

Comment: Windows 8 only, need it for W10